# Can "pros and cons" be capitalized?

Tags: nouns, capitalization

Some people tend to capitalize the phrase "**pros and cons**" in the middle of the sentence and write it as "**Pros and Cons**". Should this be considered a grammatical error?

Thank you.

Comment: It would be nice if you included a link to a place where you have seen this, or copied some text, so we could examine the context. It's hard to answer the question definitively without an example or two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a spelling error.  However, randomly capitalizing nouns to lend emphasis to them was common up to the 19th century.  See for an example the original text of the Declaration of Independence, which begins "When in the Course of human events..."

Comment: I like the way you differentiated between a grammatical error and a spelling error.